# "Favour facts over interpretations"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I'd like to express the concept that someone prefers trusting facts in lieu of interpretations. I'm no native speaker, so I've checked several websites for the idiom but with no result. Is it possible to say

*he favours/privileges facts over interpretations*

What will be the best way to express the concept? Thank you.

Comment: Look for *sceptic rationalist*, maybe helpful.

Comment: 'i'll believe it when i see it'?

Comment: ***A doubting Thomas*** is an idiomatic expression you may use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubting_Thomas

Comment: Thanks for your replies! If I want to keep it as a phrase, is "favours facts over interpretations" acceptable to a native speaker?

Comment: I'm not sure that 'interpretations' is really the word you want, almost all facts are subject to interpretation so there isn't an either/or choice between the two. I wonder if you want to say that he prefers facts to theories, or facts to beliefs.

Comment: @BoldBen yes, I should probably clarify the context. I am discussing a certain phenomenon, and I want to stress that the discourse about it (its representations, interpretations etc) is more important than what actually happened (the facts). In this sense, I would like to say my research favours interpretations over facts (I put the opposite in the OP example because it was easier to understand), but I don't know if it's acceptable.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Would you mind providing a scenario so that we can more easily understand what you mean by *fact* and *interpretation*? (Please do it by [edit]ing your question.) For example, you might say "Bob saw the shadow and said a bird flew by. Fact = shadow, interpretation = bird"; or "Bob gave Alice $10. Fact = exchange of money, interpretation = reason for the exchange; etc.

Comment: I would say "He favors facts over interpretations" would be a good way to succinctly and accurately describe this characteristic in a person.  There are other ways of putting it, but most are too easy to, er, misinterpret.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to say what you suggested - no problem. But "*the best way*" is off-topic because it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: In either the example in the question as presented or in the flipped version mentioned in your comment, you could consider using "doesn't let [X] [get in the way of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english-thesaurus/get-in-the-way-of-something) [Y]." with the appropriate nouns in their appropriate order, i.e., "S/he never lets [his/her] interpretations/opinions/observations/politics/truth get in the way of the facts." ... "S/he never lets the facts get in the way of his/her/[the] interpretations/opinions/observations/politics/[truth]."

Answer (score 2):

***"He favours facts over interpretations."***

is totally fine to use.

Alternately :

***"He prefers concrete facts over guesses and interpretations."***

Or perhaps *"verifiable facts"*

Similar :

***"He doesn't like to make assumptions beyond the proven facts he's been given."***

--- *edit* ---

Just remembered one I like a lot.

***"She prefers known facts rather than jumping to conclusions."***

*"[If someone jumps to conclusions, they decide too quickly that something is true, when they do not know all the facts.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leap+to+conclusions)"*

---

To clarify a bit.

The word *"interpretation"* is used in different situations (from explaining the finding of a scientific study ... to explaining what a piece of art means). But it always implies a personal understanding or guess, rather than presenting a series of known facts.

=========================================
**Interpretation** used to mean :

A personal **explanation** or **understanding** of a series of facts
 -- sometimes wrong or *misinterpreted*. 
=========================================

The way a person *interpreted* or **understood** the information they saw.

*"To be polite, he gestured for a high-five. His friend --unfamiliar with high-fives-- **interpreted** this as a rude gesture for rejection and was offended."*

*"After reading the study, he understood it to mean that cigarettes do not cause cancer. 

But that was just his **interpretation**.*
*He showed it to his friend, who pointed out a paragraph he had misread."*

=========================================
**Interpretation** used to mean :

A **hypothesis** *inspired by* information or
an **inference** to *explain meaning* behind known facts 
=========================================

Taking the information given, and **assuming** that it implies something else must also be true 
(despite having no evidence connecting the facts to the new idea).

*"He had smoked for years, but still didn't have cancer.

He **interpreted** this to mean that cigarettes liked him, and would not give him cancer."*

*"She **interpreted** the main character's silence at the end of the book to mean that the character did in fact know where the treasure was buried, but wasn't going to tell anyone."*

===============================================
**The following is a real-life example of a bad interpretation** 
**that tried to explain a known fact :**
===============================================

Before the Olympics all Olympians are tested to make sure they're not using drugs for an unfair advantage.

**Fact** : 
 In 2010 Jake Gibb's urine test had abnormally high levels of beta-hCG.

**Interpretation** : 
"He must be using steroids." So he was suspended from competing.

**New Fact** : 
 Jake Gibb was diagnosed with testicular cancer.

"According to the scientific literature, elevated beta-hCG levels can be the result of testicular cancer."

In the end he was allowed to compete.

[source](http://www.thetruthaboutforensicscience.com/false-positives-and-bad-interpretation-of-analytical-chemistry-results-happen-case-study-of-jake-gibb/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, ***grounded in fact*** helps.

TFD(idioms):

> **[grounded in (actual) fact](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grounded+in+fact)**
>   *Fig*. based on facts.
>   This movie is grounded in fact.
>   The stories in this book are all grounded in actual fact.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.

Comment: Thanks @alwayslearning ! Actually, I wanted to keep the opposition facts v interpretations, if possible. If you are a native speaker, how does "favours facts over interpretations" sound to you?

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your opposite version in your comment under the OP :

> "I want to stress that the discourse about it (its representations, interpretations etc) is more important than what actually happened (the facts). In this sense, I would like to say my research favours interpretations over facts"

For this scenario, saying *"this research favours interpretations over facts"* might be the best way to put it succinctly. I don't know of any idioms that mean the same.

Or perhaps *"The possibilities that could explain these facts are more important to investigate/follow up on/discuss than the facts themselves."*

---

The following phrase might help you :

> "The whole is greater than the sum of its parts."

From [the Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/more-greater-than-the-sum-of-its-parts):

> "If you say that something is more than the sum of its parts or greater than the sum of its parts, you mean that it is better [or different] than you would expect from the individual parts, because the way they combine adds a different quality."

In mathematics, this is not true.

But an assembled car can accomplish more
than its parts just lying on the ground, unassembled.

The human mind + the experience of being alive itself
takes place in the individual neurons of the brain. 
But the whole mind --and your experience itself-- 
is more than just the sum of atoms alone.

---

An excellent example of this from Philosophy of Mind 
is the thought experiment called "Mary's Room".

[The thought experiment](http://www.philosophy-index.com/jackson/marys-room/) goes like this :

> Mary lives her entire life in a room devoid of colour—she has never directly experienced colour in her entire life, though she is capable of it. Through black-and-white books and other media, she is educated on neuroscience to the point where she becomes an expert on the subject. Mary learns everything there is to know about the perception of colour in the brain, as well as the physical facts about how light works in order to create the different colour wavelengths. It can be said that Mary is aware of all physical facts about colour and colour perception.
>
> After Mary’s studies on colour perception in the brain are complete, she exits the room and experiences, for the very first time, direct colour perception. She sees the colour red for the very first time, and learns something new about it — namely, what red looks like.

When Mary experiences colour for the first time:
She learns no new science.
She learns no new facts about colour.
But she discovers what it is like to experience colour for the first time -- even though she already knows all the scientific facts about colours.

So in this example,

discussing + **interpreting** what happens when Mary sees a colour for the first time

is much more than just describing the **facts** (physics of light and atoms).